# In Ruby, why is the accumulator called memo in the inject/reduce methods?

Tags: ruby

Out of curiosity, why is the accumulator called memo in the inject/reduce methods?  Is there some context/history behind its naming?  Does it actually mean "memo" or does memo stand for something?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Comment: I always though it stood for [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: Did you see the [memo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memo) about [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fy3rjQGc6lA)?

Comment: aha - thanks for making my day more interesting!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"memo"` means in memory,that inject uses throughout its full iteration to hold the intermediate object state,to use it for its next iteration.

Answer (score 4):

i do not have a reliable source for this claim, but i think it is short for "memory" as this information is kept between iterations.